# whether the difference of two ode solutions monotone

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a problem from my ODE course:

> Let $f(x,y)$ and $F(x,y)$ be continuously differentiable functions defined on an open region $\Omega$ in the plane, and for any $(x,y) \in \Omega$, we have $f(x,y) \leq F(x,y)$. Let the solutions to the initial value problem $y'=f(x,y)$ and $y'=F(x,y)$ with the same initial condition $y(x_0)=y_0$ be $y=\varphi(x)$ and $y=\Phi(x)$, respectively, where $(x_0,y_0) \in \Omega$. Let $d(x)=\Phi(x)-\varphi(x)$. Is $d(x)$ monotonically increasing?

This is not always true. I use MATLAB and find $F(x,y)=f(x,y)+1=x-y^2+1$ is a counterexample. But I need some examples that are easy to prove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use equations where both $\Phi(x)$ and $\phi(x)$ tend to zero as $x$ tends to infinity: then the gap between the solutions must narrow to zero, so not be monotonically increasing. For example, $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-y^2$ and$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-2y^2$: certainly $-y^2 \ge -2y^2$, and the solutions are $\phi(x)=\dfrac{1}{x+y_0^{-1}}$,  $\Phi(x)=\dfrac{1}{2x+y_0^{-1}}$: as $x \rightarrow \infty$, both tend to zero (for positive $y_0$). For instance, when $y_0=\frac{1}{2}$, $d(x)=\dfrac{x}{2(x+1)(x+2)}$, which has a maximum at $x=\sqrt{2}$.